# getting the wrong output by code of finding a pair of items the list in a given list whose sum is equal a given integer

Tags: c++, output, hashtable

I have been trying to write a program which checks if there are any two items in some list L whose sum is equal to a given integer S, and prints those two items found. The program  provides an error message of "!ok"  when there is no solution available.

Input:
On the first line there will be an integer T representing the number of test cases, followed by 2 input lines for each test case:
On the first line of each test case, there will be 2 integers S and E, where S is the expected sum and E is the number of elements in the list.
On the second line, there will be E integers separated by a space.
Each integer represents an element of the list L. The elements are not sorted in any way and some could have the same value. In cases where the number E is 0, the second line will be empty.

All values for the elements of list L will be in the same range as the value S.

output:
For each test case , the output should one contains ass following:
If there is an unique solution, two elements x and y (of the list L) should be printed, separated by a single space.
If there are multiple solutions- only  the first complete pair that appears on the list and provides the correct sum will be printed. 
If there is no solution- the error message "!OK" should be printed.

Constraints and notes:

1≤T≤1000

-10^6≤S≤10^6​

0≤E≤2⋅10^4

The sum of values of E is at most 10^7

In order to perform that task, I Have tried to use hash-table , since using arrays might be problematic in this case considering run time complexity.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

int main() 

{

    long long  int   numberElements=0, number;
    long long  int  sum=0, temp;
    unordered_set<long long int> s; 
    bool found=0;
    int numberCases;
    cin >> numberCases;

    for(int c = 1; c<=numberCases; c++)
    {
        s.clear();

        cin >> sum;

        found=0;
        cin>> numberElements;
        if(numberElements==0)
            cout << "!OK" <<endl;


        else
        {

        for(long long int  i = 0; i< numberElements && found==0; i++)
          {

            cin >> number;

           if (sum==(number+number))
             {
             if (s.find(number)!=s.end() )
              {
               cout<<number<<" "<<number<<endl;
               found=1;
              }
             }

           else
             {
               if(s.find(number)==s.end())
                 s.insert(number);

                 temp = sum - number; 

               if (s.find(temp)!=s.end())
               { cout<<temp<<" "<<number<<endl;
                 found=1; 
               }
             }  
         }
           if (found==0)
           cout << "!OK" <<endl;

      }
  }

    return 0;
}
```

For the following input:

```
6
8 4
1 2 4 4
8 4
1 2 7 9
8 4
1 2 8 9
8 4
4 5 3 4
8 4
4 1 1 8
8 4
-1 1 9 8
```

The expected output is:

```
4 4
1 7
!OK
3 5
!OK
-1 9
```

whereas the output of my code is actually:

```
!OK
1 7
1 8
4 5
!OK
!OK
```

I have been trying to detect the source of the problem in my code that causes the unwanted output, but till my efforts have risen no success.
Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i did some modifications. The first was created an unordered_multiset, this allows store repeated values (this is usefull to check is sum = (number + number)).
The main problem was that you were checking an empty list, so the problem never found any value to compare.
Regards!

```
int main()
{

long long  int   numberElements = 0, number;
long long  int  sum = 0, temp;
unordered_multiset<long long int> s;  //Change set to multiset because multicase store repeated values, set don´t
bool found = 0;
bool RepeatedValue = false;
int numberCases;

cin >> numberCases;

for (int c = 1; c <= numberCases; c++)
{
    s.clear();

    cin >> sum;

    found = 0;
    cin >> numberElements;
    if (numberElements == 0)
        cout << "!OK" << endl;


    else
    {
        //This for is necesarry to charge the numbers before anlyze them. 
        //You were looking for a coincidence into a empty list

        for (long long int i = 0; i < numberElements; i++)
        {
            cin >> number;
            s.insert(number);
        }

        for (unordered_multiset<long long int>::iterator it = s.begin(); it != s.end() && found == 0;it++)
        {
            number = (*it);

            if (sum == (number + number))
            {
                //I addded this new conditional because I fill the list before analyze other number
                //In this case, use a find() is useless because always will a find a int of value "number"
                //count() returns the repeated times that a value was repeated

                if ( s.count(number) > 1)       
                {
                    cout << number << " " << number << endl;
                    found = 1;
                }
            }

            else
            {
                //This conditional is unnecessary, is find() returns s.end() 
                //means that not found the required number

                /*if (s.find(number) == s.end())
                    s.insert(number);*/

                temp = sum - number;

                if (s.find(temp) != s.end())
                {
                    cout << temp << " " << number << endl;
                    found = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        if (found == 0)
            cout << "!OK" << endl;

    }

}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: it seems that you did not understand...I have to print the first appropriate pair (if there is any) according  to the order in which it appears in the original list...your solution may not specifically print the first pair which provides the correct , but other pairs...

Answer (score 0):

I have just succeeded writing the right solution to the problem.  Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <set>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
long long  int   numberElements = 0, number;
long long  int  sum = 0, temp=0, element1=0, element2=0;
unordered_multiset<long long int> s;  
bool found = 0;
int numberCases;

cin >> numberCases;

for (int c = 1; c <= numberCases; c++)
{
    s.clear();

    cin >> sum;

    cin >> numberElements;
    if (numberElements == 0)
        cout << "!OK" << endl;


    else
    {
        found=0;

        for (long long int i = 0; i < numberElements; i++)
        {

            cin >> number;
            s.insert(number);
            if (found==0)
          {
              temp=sum-number;
              if(temp==number)
              {
                  if(s.count(temp)>1)
                  {
                      element1=number;
                      element2=number;
                      found=1;
                  }
              }

            else
              {
                  if(s.find(temp)!=s.end())
                    { 
                      element1=number;
                      element2=temp;
                      found=1;
                    }

              }
          }
        }


         if (found==1)   
            cout << min(element2,element1) << " " << max(element2, element1) << endl;
         else
            cout << "!OK" << endl;

      }

  }

   return 0;
}
```